# python - UnicodeEncodeError, need fix

Tags: python, windows, atom-editor, python-unicode

I am trying to use a simple python print statement.

```
print('这是')
```

But I am getting these issues.
[image]
I am using windows. Atom IDE. python 3.6.5
Regards,
Bhanu.

Answer (score 0):

Add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the top of your python script

Also, add the letter u before your string's opening quote:
`print(u'这是')`

Should work now. Will update with some more background to this VERY common stumbling block of strings, raw strings, Unicode, bytes, ASCII, encoding, decoding, etc.

Comment: not resolved.. is it working in your atom editor? in IDLE it is working but my daily driver is ATOM.. it is not working there

Comment: I see. Have you tried manual encoding? In other words, using `u"your string".encode('utf-8')`

Comment: I should add, I recreated this without using the Atom IDE and then resolved  the same way (command line and vim to run my .py file).